# Default GAE service missing from Stackdriver Error Reporting

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have two Google App Engine Standard env services within a project.  The second service (PHP 5.5) is fine, but the 'default' instance has disappeared from Stackdriver Error Reporting after switching the runtime to PHP 7.2 (I think... I'm not definite on the point it disappeared).

'Default' is still available in Stackdriver > Logs Viewer, but while this displays 500 errors, it doesn't provide details of the exception.

'Default' service is missing from the Stackdriver > Error Reporting > 'All services' select input, even if I set the time frame prior to the point it disappeared, much like its been deleted from Stackdriver.

I've worked through https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/php and added everything relevant except ...

```
auto_prepend_file='/project-dir/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php'
```

... as there's nothing in the docs to suggest what /project-dir/ is.  I tried setting this to ...

```
/VENDOR-PARENT-DIR/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php
```

and

```
/PROJECT-NAME/VENDOR-PARENT-DIR/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php
```

... either of which display an error in the browser after deploying, which I assume is related to an error within php.ini.  Taking this line out of php.ini and re-deploying resumes normal service.

Is anybody able to provide some pointers, please?  I've got a 500 in QA which I can't replicate locally and I'm fumbling in the dark with no error reporting on the GAE instance.

Thanks

Comment: As per my comment on George's answer, 500 errors are also visible within 'Logs Viewer' by selecting /var/log/nginx/error.log from the report type filter (not enabled by default and removes on page refresh).  It has no line breaks, so reading a stack trace is awkward, but at least I can now see the cause of the 500 errors.

Comment: Hello Andy,

You will need to open a tech support case to further investigate this issue with Google Cloud Platform technical support. Click this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/) to get more information about tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that only errors containing a stack trace will be processed to Stackdriver Error Reporting.The service name will not appear on the dropdown if no log containing a stack trace is generated.
However, you can review all logs on Stackdriver Logging page.

Review the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/app-engine-standard-environment) for more details.
Also review the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/) for more details on Stackdriver Trace.

Comment: There is a stack trace.  I've had several different 500's on this service, but it is still missing from Stackdriver Error Reporting.  Since posting this question, I'v efound that /var/log/nginx/error.log can be included within the filter in 'Logs Viewer', which contains the 500, although is not formatted.  Its obviously useful, but awkward to work with, given there are no line breaks in the stack trace.